# How do I commit only a portion of changes in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have made a small change to a file, that I'd like to commit&push right away. But how can I commit only this file from the VSCode GUI (I don't want other changes to be committed at the same time) ?

I can of course run the command line myself but I'd like to use the GUI for this and other similar instances in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to ensure that there are not other changes on `git stage` by executing:

`Git Unstage all changes`

Then if you want to include a whole file, execute:

`Git: Stage changes`

or, if you want to include a range of changes (similar to `git add --patch`), visually select the changes, and execute:

`Git: Stage selected ranges`